# Use Dominated Convergence Theorem to change order of summation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is probably not so difficult, I just want to make it clear for myself.

Let $(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space.

Assume you have $f_{n} := \sum_{k = 1}^{n} h(x,k) $ and that $|f_{n}| \leq g$  $ \forall n$ and $g$ is integrable.

How can I use DCT to justify that

$\sum_{k}^{\infty} \int_{A} h(x,k) d\mu = \int_{A} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}h(x,k) $, where $A \in \mathfrak{A}$?

From DCT it is clear that $\lim_{n} \int_{A} f_{n} d\mu = \lim_{n} \int_{A} \sum_{k}^{n}h(x,k)$ = $\int_{A} \sum_{k}^{\infty}h(x,k)$

If $n$ is finite, then $ \int_{A} \sum_{k = 1}^{n}h(x,k)d\mu = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \int_{A}h(x,k)d\mu$. Is it straightforward to go from

$\lim_{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \int_{A} h(x,k)d\mu = \int_{A} \lim_{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} h(x,k) d\mu $?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n  a_n$ by definition, so you have already demonstrated the result.

Comment: One warning. You also need that $f_n \to f$ a.e for DCT to hold.

Comment: yes, thx I forgot to write that.

Comment: @Erik You can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

and also you have to check that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f_k=0.$

Comment: This would be better as a comment.